# converting from Java script Json to Scala Json without eleminating field name for update operation

Tags: scala, slick, playscalajs

I use a function to convert from a json information sent from the front end:

```
  def convertFromJson(json: JsValue): Item = {

Item(
  (json \ "id").asOpt[String],
  (json \ "name").asOpt[String],
  (json \ "project").asOpt[String],
  (json \ "price").asOpt[scala.math.BigDecimal],
  if ((json \ "quantity").asOpt[String].contains("NaN"))
    { 
        None 
    } 
  else 
    {
        (json \ "quantity").asOpt[scala.math.BigDecimal]

    }
)

  }
```

If a normal number like 2.0 for the quantity field is entered then I wll be able to see a json object like:

```
{"id":"5aa7367","quantity":2}
```

The problem is that if my front end sends a NaN value to the back end for the Quantity field then I get:

```
{"id":"5aa7367"}
```

Is there a way to have something like  {"id":"5aa7367","quantity":None}. Quantity has been declared as BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you figured it out otherwise, but here's my take - 
the `quantity` seems to get returned as empty for NaN case, so you should simply get `None` ?

```
  if ((json \ "quantity").asOpt[Int].isEmpty)
```

Comment: I still have the problem. The data type for quantity is Option[int] . However, I believe the problem I got is related to the json parser.  We are investigating anyway. Thx

Comment: as Option[Int] you should get None for NaN - doesn't that solve your problem? (changed accordingly)

Comment: The default json parser eliminates the information of the field name that will have the None value. For us, this info is important to make updates as we need to be able to update quantity to Null in the Database.

Comment: Not sure I understand - doesn't this do that?

Comment: The problem I have is that for some reason the field name quantity disappears from the returned object so I get {"id":"5aa7367"} and I can not get something like:   {"id":"5aa7367","quantity":None}. By loosing the field name "quantity" I can not update this field to None (and just this one as it is the only one that appears in the json) and therefore I can not update its respective db field to Null

Comment: But you should be returning `None` in your `Item` object, if quantity is either missing or not a Int. Or am I missing something? You are mentioning Json so I'm confused here.

Comment: After the json is converted to a scala object it has to be processed by slick. The converted object losses the name of the field I need to update so Slick does not update anything. Yet, the goal was to update that field to a NILL value in the database